# Django session cookie expiry date

Tags: django, python-3.x, cookies, session-cookies

I am running a django (1.10) site. In settings, I have defined `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60*60*24*365` and it was setting the cookie expiry 1 year from creation.

Recently, the session is expiring at session end. Simply put, perhaps the session expiry is not being set although it is still defined in settings as earlier.

What can be the problem. Why the default behaviour is not being followed. I am facing the same problem in local server, testing server and production.

I understand that the question is not clear as I have no idea what is the root of the problem. What I want is setting sessionid cookie's expiry date to be one year from creation.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code takes place in `/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py`. You can see in this block of code what is going on:

```
if (modified or settings.SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST) and not empty:
    if request.session.get_expire_at_browser_close():
        max_age = None
        expires = None
    else:
        max_age = request.session.get_expiry_age()
        expires_time = time.time() + max_age
        expires = cookie_date(expires_time)

    # Save the session data and refresh the client cookie.
    # Skip session save for 500 responses, refs #3881.
    if response.status_code != 500:
        try:
            request.session.save()
        except UpdateError:
            raise SuspiciousOperation(
                "The request's session was deleted before the "
                "request completed. The user may have logged "
                "out in a concurrent request, for example."
            )
        response.set_cookie(
            settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
            request.session.session_key, max_age=max_age,
            expires=expires, domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
            path=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH,
            secure=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE or None,
            httponly=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY or None,
        )
```

If `get_expire_at_browser_close()` returns true, regardless of the expiry age, its going to set the session to expire when the browser closes. Use a debugger or a print statement to check why/if that function is returning true. If it isn't returning true, it may be a browser/configuration issue. You can see exactly what Django is writing out in the set_cookie function at the end. If everything there looks good your issue might be on the browser side.

Comment: I have gone through this but am still confused as to why is it happening as of now. Also, this is not a browser issue as the same behaviour is occurring at other systems.

Comment: Do you have a debugger installed? Is it hitting these lines:                              
    max_age = None
    expires = None

You should be able to see exactly why it is setting it. Step into the get_expire_at_browser_close() function and see why it is returning true.

Comment: @DhiaTN Hey, I had to make change in the source code of django (this file). The problem seems to be that when you modify the cookies during handling request, it was setting the expiry date to be None. For simplicity, I just defined the cookie expiry date outside the if else condition for the time being. It's just a temporary solution. Also, perhaps this problem is not occurring in django 1.11